# Biopython: SeqIO.parse() FileNotFoundError

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

I'm new in Bioinformatics and Biopython, so I have some difficulties with it.

I was reading the Biopython (SeqIO) documentation, but when I try to execute some SeqIO.parse() commands I get FileNotFoundError.

For example, I want to get "example.fasta" file (which I don't have it on my PC). I try to do it with this command:

```
for record in SeqIO.parse("example.fasta", "fasta"):
    print(record.id)
```

But, all I get is **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `SeqIO.parse` provides a way of parsing a provided fasta file and neatly separating the header information from the sequence information etc. It sounds like you want to download a fasta file, which is a completely different task. This is quite a fundamental misunderstanding, I suggest you seek help/guidance from someone you work with, good luck!

Comment: exactly, you do need to have `example.fasta` in your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that [`FileNotFoundError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError) occurs when the code tries to open a file on your computer and does not find it.

This can happen either because you simply do not have this file, or you gave the name with a typo, or the path to the file is not correct (This is [an important notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)): the path to the file should be absolute, or relative to the current working directory (usually the one from which you executed the python script)).

As suggested in the comments to your question, you seem to be expecting `SeqIO.parse` to get the file for you. This is not the case. The first argument you give to this function (in the example "example.fasta") is the path to an existing file that you want to "parse", that is, interpret its information content and make this content available to the rest of your program in a convenient form.

So in order to get this example working, you first need to get a fasta file. If you do not already have one, you can download some manually from genbank, or find one in the biopython installation (if you installed it from source and know where the source code is located), for instance in `Tests/Quality/example.fasta`.